# Recursion Error: Maximum Recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, scikit-learn, nltk, stemming

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, codecs, nltk.stem

english_stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/corpus/source-document/test1"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                posts = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self.build_analyzer())
        return lambda doc: (english_stemmer.stem(w) for w in  analyzer(doc))

vectorizer = StemmedCountVectorizer(min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(posts)
num_samples, num_features = X_train.shape
print("#samples: %d, #features: %d" % (num_samples, num_features))     #samples: 5, #features: 25
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

When I run the above code for all the text file contained in the directory it is throwing the following error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

I tried to resolve the problem with sys.setrecursionlimit, but all in vain. When i provide large value like 20000 the the kernel crash error occurs.

Comment: Try replacing `super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self.build_analyzer())` with `super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()`

Comment: Thanks.. It works for me

Comment: what is the point of opening the file like that? if there is more than one you end up opening all of them and only working with the last one opened. make that a function the return that opened file or add some break or if you want to work with several files, add them to a list or just open the file directly if you know where it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in `analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self.build_analyzer())` here you are calling the function `build_analyzer` before the super call, which cause a infinite recursive loop. Change it for `analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()`